Find one value between two lists of dicts, then find another same value based on first similarity
This is my code:

from collections import defaultdict

ip_port_device = [

    {'ip': '192.168.1.140', 'port_number': 4, 'device_name': 'device1'},
    {'ip': '192.168.1.128', 'port_number': 8, 'device_name': 'device1'},
    {'ip': '192.168.1.56', 'port_number': 14, 'device_name': 'device1'},
    {'ip': '192.168.1.61', 'port_number': 4, 'device_name': 'device1'},
    {'ip': '192.168.1.78', 'port_number': 8, 'device_name': 'device1'},
    {'ip': '192.168.1.13', 'port_number': 16, 'device_name': 'device1'},

    {'ip': '192.168.2.140', 'port_number': 4, 'device_name': 'device2'},
    {'ip': '192.168.2.128', 'port_number': 8, 'device_name': 'device2'},
    {'ip': '192.168.2.56', 'port_number': 14, 'device_name': 'device2'},
    {'ip': '192.168.2.61', 'port_number': 4, 'device_name': 'device2'},
    {'ip': '192.168.2.78', 'port_number': 8, 'device_name': 'device2'},
    {'ip': '192.168.2.13', 'port_number': 16, 'device_name': 'device2'},

    {'ip': '192.168.3.140', 'port_number': 4, 'device_name': 'device3'},
    {'ip': '192.168.3.128', 'port_number': 8, 'device_name': 'device3'},
    {'ip': '192.168.3.56', 'port_number': 14, 'device_name': 'device3'},
    {'ip': '192.168.3.61', 'port_number': 4, 'device_name': 'device3'},
    {'ip': '192.168.3.78', 'port_number': 8, 'device_name': 'device3'},
    {'ip': '192.168.3.13', 'port_number': 16, 'device_name': 'device3'},

]

ip_per_node = [

    {'node_name': 'server9.example.com', 'ip_address': '192.168.1.140'},
    {'node_name': 'server19.example.com', 'ip_address': '192.168.1.128'},
    {'node_name': 'server11.example.com', 'ip_address': '192.168.2.140'},
    {'node_name': 'server21.example.com', 'ip_address': '192.168.2.128'},
    {'node_name': 'server17.example.com', 'ip_address': '192.168.3.140'},
    {'node_name': 'server6.example.com', 'ip_address': '192.168.3.128'},

]

ips_and_ports_in_switch = []
for compute in ip_per_node:
    for port in ip_port_device:
        if compute['ip_address'] == port['ip']:
            port = port['port_number']
            for new_port in ip_port_device:
                if port == new_port['port_number']:
                    ips_and_ports_in_switch.append({
                        'port_number': new_port['port_number'],
                        'ip_address': new_port['ip'],
                        'node_name': compute['node_name'],
                        'device_name': new_port['device_name']
                        })

concatenated = defaultdict(list)
for entry in ips_and_ports_in_switch:
    concatenated[(entry['device_name'], entry['port_number'], entry['node_name'])].append(entry['ip_address'])


The logic is:
if ip_per_node['ip_address'] matches ip_port_device['ip'], then in ip_port_device find all ips have the same port number.
Then save like this (expected output):
node server9.example.com, port 4, device device1, ips ['192.168.1.140', '192.168.1.61']
node server19.example.com, port 8, device device1, ips ['192.168.1.128', '192.168.1.78']
node server11.example.com, port 4, device device2, ips ['192.168.2.140', '192.168.2.61']
node server21.example.com, port 8, device device2, ips ['192.168.2.128', '192.168.2.78']
node server17.example.com, port 4, device device3, ips ['192.168.3.140', '192.168.3.61']
node server6.example.com, port 8, device device3, ips ['192.168.3.128', '192.168.3.78']

My current code doesn't work as I expect. It saves one port multiple times for all nodes.
I tried to add least but needed data for the sample.

# loop both lists to match nodes with port_number and device_name
for item in ip_port_device:
    for node in ip_per_node:
        if item["ip"] == node["ip_address"]:
            node.update(
                {
                    "port_number": item["port_number"],
                    "device_name": item["device_name"],
                    "ips": [item["ip"]],
                }
            )

# loop both lists again to get ips that have no direct correspondence in ip_per_node
for item in ip_port_device:
    for node in ip_per_node:
        if (
            item["port_number"] == node["port_number"]
            and item["device_name"] == node["device_name"]
            and item["ip"] not in node["ips"]
        ):
            node["ips"].append(item["ip"])


for node in ip_per_node:
    print(f'node {node['node_name']}, port {node['port_number']}, device {node['device_name']}, ips {node['ips']}')

node server9.example.com, port 4, device device1, ips ['192.168.1.140', '192.168.1.61']
node server19.example.com, port 8, device device1, ips ['192.168.1.128', '192.168.1.78']
node server11.example.com, port 4, device device2, ips ['192.168.2.140', '192.168.2.61']
node server21.example.com, port 8, device device2, ips ['192.168.2.128', '192.168.2.78']
node server17.example.com, port 4, device device3, ips ['192.168.3.140', '192.168.3.61']
node server6.example.com, port 8, device device3, ips ['192.168.3.128', '192.168.3.78']


The modifications needed to get it to produce the expected results is as follows (comments with Booboo in it are the major changes made to your code)
ip_port_device = [

    {'ip': '192.168.1.140', 'port_number': 4, 'device_name': 'device1'},
    {'ip': '192.168.1.128', 'port_number': 8, 'device_name': 'device1'},
    {'ip': '192.168.1.56', 'port_number': 14, 'device_name': 'device1'},
    {'ip': '192.168.1.61', 'port_number': 4, 'device_name': 'device1'},
    {'ip': '192.168.1.78', 'port_number': 8, 'device_name': 'device1'},
    {'ip': '192.168.1.13', 'port_number': 16, 'device_name': 'device1'},

    {'ip': '192.168.2.140', 'port_number': 4, 'device_name': 'device2'},
    {'ip': '192.168.2.128', 'port_number': 8, 'device_name': 'device2'},
    {'ip': '192.168.2.56', 'port_number': 14, 'device_name': 'device2'},
    {'ip': '192.168.2.61', 'port_number': 4, 'device_name': 'device2'},
    {'ip': '192.168.2.78', 'port_number': 8, 'device_name': 'device2'},
    {'ip': '192.168.2.13', 'port_number': 16, 'device_name': 'device2'},

    {'ip': '192.168.3.140', 'port_number': 4, 'device_name': 'device3'},
    {'ip': '192.168.3.128', 'port_number': 8, 'device_name': 'device3'},
    {'ip': '192.168.3.56', 'port_number': 14, 'device_name': 'device3'},
    {'ip': '192.168.3.61', 'port_number': 4, 'device_name': 'device3'},
    {'ip': '192.168.3.78', 'port_number': 8, 'device_name': 'device3'},
    {'ip': '192.168.3.13', 'port_number': 16, 'device_name': 'device3'},

]

ip_per_node = [

    {'node_name': 'server9.example.com', 'ip_address': '192.168.1.140'},
    {'node_name': 'server19.example.com', 'ip_address': '192.168.1.128'},
    {'node_name': 'server11.example.com', 'ip_address': '192.168.2.140'},
    {'node_name': 'server21.example.com', 'ip_address': '192.168.2.128'},
    {'node_name': 'server17.example.com', 'ip_address': '192.168.3.140'},
    {'node_name': 'server6.example.com', 'ip_address': '192.168.3.128'},

]

for compute in ip_per_node:
    for entry in ip_port_device:  # Booboo
        if compute['ip_address'] == entry['ip']:
            port = entry['port_number']
            device_name = entry['device_name']  # Booboo
            ips_and_ports_in_switch = []  #Booboo
            for new_entry in ip_port_device:
                if port == new_entry['port_number'] and device_name == new_entry['device_name']:
                    ips_and_ports_in_switch.append(new_entry['ip']) # Booboo
            print(f'node {compute['node_name']}, port {port}, device {device_name}, ips {ips_and_ports_in_switch}')
            break  #Booboo

Prints:
node server9.example.com, port 4, device device1, ips ['192.168.1.140', '192.168.1.61']
node server19.example.com, port 8, device device1, ips ['192.168.1.128', '192.168.1.78']
node server11.example.com, port 4, device device2, ips ['192.168.2.140', '192.168.2.61']
node server21.example.com, port 8, device device2, ips ['192.168.2.128', '192.168.2.78']
node server17.example.com, port 4, device device3, ips ['192.168.3.140', '192.168.3.61']
node server6.example.com, port 8, device device3, ips ['192.168.3.128', '192.168.3.78']


Thanks, but it has an issue. For example for server9 which device is device1, it's printing all IPs of other ranges, while device1 consists only 192.168.1. I tested your code with both the example and the real-world data, but both are wrong. I again am thankful, but this has issue.

@Saeed Pardon me, but based on your one sentence description of what the "logic" is, this program does what you asked. So it is clear that your logic description was under-specified and you should really update your question to say precisely which IPs should be included. Nowhere in your original problem statement were the device name and how it should be used even mentioned. My guess is that my updated code is what you meant, but I can't be sure anymore.
